# Explicit Dehn twist for $S^n\times S^n$

Tags: differential-topology, group-actions, mapping-class-group

Fix $n$ odd and let $M=S^n\times S^n$. The diffeomorphism group Diff($M$) acts on the homology group $H_n(M)\simeq \mathbb Z^2$ inducing a surjection $d: \text{Diff}(M) \rightarrow \text{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$. I’d like a recipe for constructing an explicit diffeomorphism $f$ so that $d(f)=A$, where $A= \left(\begin{array}{ll}1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right)$.

In the case $n\ge 3$, the fact that $d$ is surjective can be found in

- Wall, *Classification of $(n-1)$-connected $2n$-manifolds*, Corollary to Theorem 1, or
- Wall, *Classification problems in differential topology II*, Lemma 10.

However, the argument (which applies when $M$ is any $(n-1)$-connected $2n$ manifolds for $n\ge3$) goes through something like the h-cobordism theorem, so it's not explicit. I'm hoping there is a more concrete description in the special case $M=S^n\times S^n$.

In the case $n=1$, one can use that SL$(2,\mathbb Z)$ acts on the plane $\mathbb R^2$ preserving the integer lattice $\mathbb Z^2$, inducing an action on $\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2\simeq S^1\times S^1$. Alternatively, the diffeomorphism $A\in\text{Diff}(S^1\times S^1)$ is isotopic to a Dehn twist $T$ about the meridian curve (or maybe it’s the longitude), and $T$ is supported on an annulus, where it can be described by the formula 
\begin{array}{ccc}
T:&S^1\times[1,2]&\rightarrow& S^1\times[1,2]\\ 
&(\theta, r)&\mapsto&(\theta+2\pi r, r).\end{array}

It's not clear to me how/if either of these descriptions generalize to higher dimensions. Any reference or suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Higher-dimensional Dehn twists are usually asked to take place in $T^*S^n$. See [this note](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~skdona/MCGROUP.PDF) for an explicit model of one. Luckily, I can find a copy of $T^*S^n$ in your manifold - a tubular neighborhood of the antidiagonal. Maybe a Dehn twist along this will work for you? (What happens when you do a Dehn twist along the diagonal in the torus?)

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks for the reference! I really want a diffeomorphism representing the matrix $A$. (Perhaps I shouldn't call it a Dehn twist.) On the torus, the diagonal Dehn twist is given by the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{ll}2&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right)$. I wonder if conjugates of this element generate SL(2,Z). In any case, I find it hard to believe that there isn't a concrete description of a diffeomorphism representing $A$...

Comment: There probably is! I just don't know it. The Dehn twist above at least gives you presumably a similar matrix for $S^n \times S^n$, so maybe you could go from there.

Comment: The statement that $d$ is surjective is not correct. Wall proved that those automorphisms of $H_n(M;\mathbb{Z})$ realized by diffeomorphism is the subgroup of that those preserve the intersection form and its quadratic refinement. This can certainly be smaller than $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, for $S^n \times S^n$ with $n$ even it only has four elements.

Comment: Thanks for the response @skupers. In my question I am restricting to $n$ odd. In any case, I see your point about the quadratic refinement. Perhaps I should then ask instead for a diffeomorphism that induces $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&2\\0&1\end{array}\right)$, since this seems to preserve the quadratic refinement for any (odd) $n$. Do you know a construction of an explicit diffeomorphism in this case?